# Interlaced tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to typeset a character sheet for Call of Cthulhu. I want to create a table containing combat skills, and for each skill, a list of weapons.

To typeset the skill table, I'd use something like that :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{Xccc}
...
\end{tabularx}
```

And for the weapon table, I'd use something like this :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{Xcccc}
...
\end{tabular}
```

But for 1 line of the first table, I need to insert 2 or 3 lines of the second. Like this :

```
skill 1             1  2  3
weapon 1     12  23  34  45
weapon 2     12  23  34  45
skill 2             1  2  3
weapon 3     12  23  34  45
```

How can I achieve this ?

I may compose the table using this :

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\wbox}[1]{%
    \makebox[1.2em]{\centering #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{12cm}{Xccccc}
    \textbf{Arme} & \textbf{Portée} & \textbf{Dégats} & \textbf{Panne} & \textbf{CAD} & \textbf{CAP} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Corps à corps}} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{\wbox{50}/\wbox{50}/\wbox{10} \%} \\
    Mains nues & 1 & 1D3+1D4 & - & - & - \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Combat à distance}} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{\wbox{40}/\wbox{20}/\wbox{8} \%} \\
    Revolver cal 22 & 50 & 1D6 & 98 & 1 & 6 \\
    Mitraillette & 70 & 1D10 & 96 & 6 & 20 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of `\multicolumn` ? I find them ugly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a sketch on how the desired alignment should look like? Are the values in a "weapon"  row smehow aligned with the values in a "skill"  row? Could you please also include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far?

Comment: Why not simply use something like `\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{Xcccc}
skill 1  &       &    1&  2&  3 \\
weapon 1 &    12 & 23  &34 & 45 \\
weapon 2 &    12 & 23  &34 & 45 \\
skill 2  &       &    1&  2&  3 \\
weapon 3 &    12 & 23  &34 & 45 \\
\end{tabularx}`?  Where the second column is left empty in "skill" rows.

Comment: Because the skills line are a bit more complicated than I described. Values of a skill line are separated with "/", and it is better to keep values close to each other, for readbility. Values of a weapon line are wider, so it would stretch skills values. And also keeping the two kinds of line not aligned make them visually different, keeping them easier to identify.

Comment: Could you please include an image of auch a table as a reference? I think this is way easier than trying to guess what the desired output should look like based in descriptions.

Comment: Probably `\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{Xcccc}
skill 1  &    \multicolumn{3}{l}{1 / 2 / 3}    \\
weapon 1 &    12 & 23  &34 & 45 \\
\end{tabularx}` is closer?

Comment: Yes, it is way closer. But slashes are not aligned.

Comment: Wild guess: The slashes in both skill rows will be aligned as long as each entry only has a single digit. If there are entries with two digits, you can add `\phantom{0}`.

Comment: Or I can use a fixed sized hbox for each value.

Comment: Using a box of fixed width is certainly also possible. You added "Is there a way to get rid of \multicolumn?"  to your question. If you would like the output to stay the same, there is as far as I know not really a possibility other than using multicolumn. If you prefer, you could however, define a custom command such as `\newcommand{\skill}[4]{\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{#1}} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{\wbox{#2}/\wbox{#3}/\wbox{#4} \%}}` and use it as follows: \skill{Combat à distance}{40}{20}{8}\\ `.